# Obejct Oriented Design Class Circle - Am I doing this right?

Tags: oop, class

Problem
Use object oriented deisgn to design a class called Circle that will receive the diameter of a circle, and calculate and display the circumference and the area of that circle.  Design the class table…write an algorithm for each operation…write a test or driver algorithm to test the solution

```
Class Table                                         
Class       
Circle      

Attributes      
diameter        

Responsibilities        
receive diameter        
calculate circumference     
calculate area      
display circumference       
display area        

Operations      
+setDiameter()      
-calculateCircumference     
-calculateArea      
+displayCircumference       
+display Area       

Algorithm  
Class Circle                                            
diameter1                                           

setDiameter (inDiameter1)                                           
  Diameter1=inDiameter1                                         
END                                         

displayDiameter()                                           
  calculateCircumference (Circumference)                                            
  calculateArea (Area)                                          
    Display "The Diameter is", Diameter1                                            
    Display "The Circumference is", Circumference                                           
    Display "The Area is", Area                                         
END                                         

calculateCircumference (Circumference)                                          
  Circumference=Diameter1*3.14                                          
END                                         

calculateArea (Area)                                            
  Area=(Diameter1*Diameter1)*3.14                                           
END                                         

Test or Driver Algorithm                                            
Create Circle as NewCircle()                                            
  testCircle()                                          
  inDiameter1=5                                         
  Circle.setDiameter (inDiameter1)                                          
  Circle.displayCircumference()                                         
  Circle.displayArea()
```

Am I doing this right???

Comment: @Roflcoptr I would imagine the design of the class and algorithms would be language agnostic.

Comment: @glowcoder yes I thought this too, but I was irritated by the END keywords.

Comment: @Roflcoptr probably some wierd requirement of the professor. When I was in uni, I had a professor mark me down because my pseudocode didn't conform to the appropriate syntax. Turns out her 'pseudocode' was a language she had written for her master's thesis, and was a hacked up version of bash and perl...

Comment: This is a PHP class but this is a generic thing that we don't have to use a specific language for, he is just gauging whether or not we understand, I'm just trying to figure out if I am on the right track

Comment: You could use a proper markup anyway.

Comment: Does your imaginary language not have a (reasonably) correct value for pi?

Comment: I do apologize for my ignorance, I am brand new at this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just a couple of problems that are trivial, really:

Your function named `displayDiameter()` is actually displaying the circumference and area in addition to the diameter; there is nothing logically wrong with this, it just seems to be an unfortunate choice of function name.

Your `calculateArea` is calculating area as `diameter`<sup>`2`</sup>`*pi`.  Shouldn't it be `1/4*diameter`<sup>`2`</sup>`*pi`?

Comment: Thank you, I will fix it, otherwise ok though?